# Which framework for C# WPF can plot line graph in real time with 30 frames per second

Tags: c#, wpf, plot

I am trying the plot data in real time with 30 frames per second in C# WPF with some framework, such as DevExpress, ComponentOne and Visifire. My approach is as follow:

A standalone thread is maintained to append data to the plot. Everytime the length of the plot is checked. If the length of the plot is equal to 50 samples, then the first sample is dropped and a new sample is appended. Therefore, the length of the plot is maintained as 50 samples.

Now I would like to refresh the plot for 30 times per second. However, none of three frameworks can achieve this refresh rate. May I ask if any one have sample code to achieve this goal?

Thank you.

Comment: If you want smooth 30fps drawing of anything you will probably need to use hardware acceleration. This would mean using OpenGL or DirectX to do the rendering for you in a context within your WPF window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Measurement Studio to achieve this. It is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I used Measurement Studio initially, but then switched to [LightningChart](http://arction.com/) due to its superior performance.

This was a few years ago, but back then with old hardware I had no problem plotting 12 signals sampled at 500 Hz with > 30 fps.

Comment: Thank you. I will have a try.